# How long woulld a merchant receive the funds after the capture moves funds from your buyer's account to your PayPal account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Paypal documentation says:

> You can capture funds, which is a request to process the payment your buyer authorized. If successful, the capture moves funds from your buyer's account to your PayPal account.
>   You can also reauthorize, which offers you a new honor period for your authorization.
>   Finally, you can void the authorization, which removes your ability to capture funds on the authorization, and returns PayPal balance funds to the buyer if applicable.
>   Note: If the capture is performed outside the honor period, there is a possibility the funds will not be available at that time.

How long woulld a merchant receive the funds after the capture moves funds from your buyer's account to your PayPal account?

Comment: In my experience it is instantaneous, as should any intra-bank transfer be for any bank, but this is a question that should be directed to Paypal.

Comment: Thanks @EJP, I asked the Paypal about it. I'm waiting for their response.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal capture (and sale transactions) instantly transfer money between the PayPal accounts involved. [Except for a few edge cases which can result in pending transactions, such as payments held for merchants who have not yet signed up, or who need to tell PayPal whether to release the funds in the payment currency or convert the payment to the merchant's default currency, etc.]

Note that this means the money instantly moves to the merchant's PayPal account; there will then be some delay involved in withdrawing these funds to an external bank account, if the merchant chooses to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a delayed capture transaction through a payment gateway? I didn't think paypal itself did delayed capture so I assume you mean through payflow pro? Or Paypal Advanced (which I understand is basically just a merchant account).

The funds will transfer basically instantly but there can be a delay for the funds to make their way from your acquirer / merchant bank to your bank account (settlement time / settlement period). If that's what you mean it should be about 1-3 days for the funds to be deposited into your bank account (each acquirer / merchant bank will have a different time-frame that you can find out by asking them or through their website).

Comment: I'm using the REST APIs of Paypal (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) and used sandbox for testing it. I executed the method **capture** to transfer the funds from buyer to merchant account.